# Optimizing machines' utilization in python

Tags: python, optimization

I need to find the best combination: maximize the efficiency or minimize the power needed (cost = output/efficiency) of 3 machines' utilization to produce a given output.
I found a library kneed https://github.com/arvkevi/kneed that can give me the optima of each efficiency curve, however the problem is more complex.

- if I need 10000 output: I would use all the output of BM5 as it has the best optima (in efficiency) and it covers the output required entirely.
- if I need 15000 output: I would use BM5 up to its optima ~10000 + BM3 up to its optima ~4000 + a little bit of extra BM5 after its optima, I guess..
- if I need 20000 output: I would use BM5 up to its optima ~10000 + BM4 up to its optima ~10000

BM5 has the highest effciency optima overall but BM3 has the the highest effciency optima for lower output, up to ~4000

If someone can point me to the correct path would be much appreciated
maybe a smart application of the fractional knapsack problem?

[image]

```
> def getMachineInfoBatch_3_b1_b2_b5(self, i1, i2, i3):
    
    e1 = 0 if i1 == -1 else self.machines[1][i1]
    e2 = 0 if i2 == -1 else self.machines[3][i2]
    e3 = 0 if i3 == -1 else self.machines[9][i3]

    o1 = 0 if i1 == -1 else self.machines[0][i1]
    o2 = 0 if i2 == -1 else self.machines[2][i2]
    o3 = 0 if i3 == -1 else self.machines[8][i3]
    
    return e1, e2, e3, o1, o2, o3

def getMachineInfoBatch_3_b1_b3_b4(self, i1, i2, i3):
    
    e1 = 0 if i1 == -1 else self.machines[1][i1]
    e2 = 0 if i2 == -1 else self.machines[5][i2]
    e3 = 0 if i3 == -1 else self.machines[7][i3]

    o1 = 0 if i1 == -1 else self.machines[0][i1]
    o2 = 0 if i2 == -1 else self.machines[4][i2]
    o3 = 0 if i3 == -1 else self.machines[6][i3]
    
    return e1, e2, e3, o1, o2, o3

def getMachineInfoBatch_3_b1_b3_b5(self, i1, i2, i3):
    
    e1 = 0 if i1 == -1 else self.machines[1][i1]
    e2 = 0 if i2 == -1 else self.machines[5][i2]
    e3 = 0 if i3 == -1 else self.machines[9][i3]

    o1 = 0 if i1 == -1 else self.machines[0][i1]
    o2 = 0 if i2 == -1 else self.machines[4][i2]
    o3 = 0 if i3 == -1 else self.machines[8][i3]
    
    return e1, e2, e3, o1, o2, o3
```

Comment: What are the machines, what is the output, how do you measure efficiency? I don't understand what are you trying to optimize.

Comment: machine are blowers, output is flow, efficiency has been given to me. the key thing here is that the graph says that for a certain flow there is different effciency for each blowers

Answer (score 2):

### This might help:

I will leave fine tuning up to you. Also be aware that this is just a brute force solution so in case you have more machines, it will explode rather fast.

```
#Data from your graph at glance. You probably want more data points for more precise outputs.
machine1 = data.frame(efficiency=c(0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8), output=c(2200, 2400, 2600, 2800, 3000 ))
machine2 = data.frame(efficiency=c(0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8), output=c(4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000))
machine3 = data.frame(efficiency=c(0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8), output=c(4100, 5100, 6100, 7100, 8100, 9100))


combinations <- data.frame(m1eff=numeric(), m2eff=numeric(), m3eff=numeric(),
                           output1=numeric(), output2=numeric(), output3=numeric(),
                           totalOutput=numeric(), requiredPower=numeric())


#I don't have exact relation for the power input required.
#So I will go by the output = power * efficiency
# o = p1 * e1 + p2 * e2 + p3 * e3
# p_total = p1 + p2 + p3
# we know o1, o2, o3, e1, e2, e3 so we can compute the power required
# and we will want to minimize that.
computeEffandPow <- function(m1eff, m1out, m2eff, m2out, m3eff, m3out) {
  totalOutput <- 0
  requiredPower <- 0
  if (m1eff > 0) {
    totalOutput <- totalOutput + m1out
    requiredPower <- requiredPower + (1/m1eff) * m1out
  }
  if (m2eff > 0) {
    totalOutput <- totalOutput + m2out
    requiredPower <- requiredPower + (1/m2eff) * m2out
  }
  if (m3eff > 0) {
    totalOutput <- totalOutput + m3out
    requiredPower <- requiredPower + (1/m3eff) * m3out
  }
  return(c(m1eff, m1out, m2eff, m2out, m3eff, m3out, requiredPower, totalOutput))
  
}

#since you have only three machines and the data set is not that large
#I shall take the brute force approach. There is most likely some neat mathematical solution
#Which unfortunately eludes me at the moment.
#So I will simply discretize your data into intervals, compute all possible combinations of output-efficiencies
#Then sort the values.
for (i in 1:nrow(machine1)) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(machine2)) {
   for (k in 1:nrow(machine3)) {
     m1eff <- machine1$efficiency[i]
     m1out <- machine1$output[i] 
     m2eff <- machine2$efficiency[j]
     m2out <- machine2$output[j] 
     m3eff <- machine3$efficiency[k]
     m3out <- machine3$output[k] 
     
     
     combinations <- rbind(combinations, computeEffandPow(m1eff, m1out, m2eff, m2out, m3eff, m3out))
     #note that this includes unnecessary duplicities
     combinations <- rbind(combinations, computeEffandPow(m1eff, m1out, m2eff, m2out, 0, 0))
     combinations <- rbind(combinations, computeEffandPow(m1eff, m1out, 0, 0, m3eff, m3out))
     combinations <- rbind(combinations, computeEffandPow(0, 0, m2eff, m2out, m3eff, m3out))
    
     combinations <- rbind(combinations, computeEffandPow(m1eff, m1out, 0, 0, 0, 0))
     combinations <- rbind(combinations, computeEffandPow(0, 0, m2eff, m2out, 0, 0))
     combinations <- rbind(combinations, computeEffandPow(0, 0, 0, 0, m3eff, m3out))
    
   } 
  }
}
#I did something wrong and the rbind killed the names.
colnames(combinations) = c("m1eff", "m1out","m2eff", "m2out","m3eff", "m3out", "reqPow", "totalOut")
#do away with duplicities
combinations <- unique(combinations)
combinations <- combinations[order(combinations$totalOut, combinations$reqPow),]


listEfficiencies <- function(combinations, requiredOutput, minimumOnly=F) {
  #here I use approximate output since I chose rather large chunks.
  #if you make the intervals smaller, the you will be able to afford smaller tolerance.
  approximateOutput <- combinations[combinations$totalOut < requiredOutput + 500 & combinations$totalOut > requiredOutput - 500, ]
  if (minimumOnly) {
    approximateOutput <- approximateOutput[which(approximateOutput$reqPow == min(approximateOutput$reqPow)),]
  }
  return(approximateOutput)
}
```

And as you can see from `listEfficiencies(combinations, 10000)`, for the output of 10000, you actually arrived at the correct solution. Your reasoning was slightly off though: The first machine is not more efficient. It only has a steeper efficiency curve.
From what I can see, all the machines can go up to 80% efficiency as long as you have them running close to their maximal output. After the peak, you can overload them a bit more, however the efficiency takes a dip.
The most efficient one is actually probably the green one(BM5) which can run at close to 85% efficiency if you have it running at its peak performance.
So basically, you want such a combination of machines, where the machines are running as close to their peak as is reasonable.

There are also other parameters to be considered - like the time it takes for the machine to rev up and the fact that machines usually don't like being turned on/off too often. Which all might impact your decision making about the balance loading of the machines.

#### Update:

As I said, with more machines it will explode. You added machines, it did. However not all is lost.

I rewrote the solution in python and optimized it to some extent. There is definitely a room for an improvement, however even if you do that you will be cutting it close to the reasonable limits.
Current performace:

- cca 40sec / 10M iterations. This means that running the whole run would take ~ 20 minutes.
- cca 3GB RAM / 50M results. This one is a tougher one since it means that if you want to store all the results, it will require further optimization.

As you mentioned in the comment, making the granularity a bit lower would help. That is one possible approach.

Alternatively if you want to keep the current granularity, you might consider storing only relevant results - e.g. keeping minimum for several values of interest (for example common target outputs) and storing the result only if it is both within some range of the minimum (e. g. output +- 10% and with efficiency that is at most a bit worse than the current minimum).
The downside to this is that you won't have full information and if you decide you want to get more knowledge about a point you didn't save, you will have to re-run whole computation once again.

Further going down the line, if you only want to answer the question: which configuration is best for output X, you can shave the computation time like this:

- First compute as many machines as you can - 4 machines would still be reasonably fast.
- Now delete all the results that are already too inefficient, or have an output that is either too low or too large to be of any use - basically only outputs that are equal to X, or within range (X - minimal output of machine 5) - (X - maximal output of machine 5)
- For those values that you didn't delete, compute required output of the machine 5.
- compare results, select minimum
- profit

For case with 5 machines this approach is good enough. If you iterate on this approach you will arrive at the BFS with pruning of branches.

```
import csv
import itertools
#since we had the data in R, i dumped them into .csv file and read them
reader = csv.reader(open('machines.csv'), delimiter=',')
machines = []
for i in range(0,10):
    machines.append([])

#a bit of bookkeeping
for line in reader:
    for i in range(0,5):
        if line[2 * i + 1] not in ["NA", "efficiency", "output"]:
            machines[2 * i + 1].append(float(line[2 * i + 1]))
            machines[2 * i].append(float(line[2 * i + 2]))

#a little more of bookkeeping - we want to retrieve the values without the need to care about the way
#the data are stored.
#also, since the memory appears to be the problem, we want to store as little data as possible and rest will
#be fetched on demand.
class MachineHolder:
    def __init__(self, machineTable):
        self.machines = machineTable

    def getLen(self, machineInd):
        return len(self.machines[machineInd * 2 + 1])

    def getLenBatch(self, indices):
        return ([x for x in map(lambda x: self.getLen(x), indices)])

    def getMachineInfo(self, machineNumber, lineIndex):
        eff = self.machines[machineNumber * 2 + 1][lineIndex]
        out = self.machines[machineNumber * 2][lineIndex]
        return (eff, out)


    def getMachineInfoBatch(self, i1, i2, i3, i4, i5):
        #I had a nice lambda here and passed indices as a tuple. The overhead was too large as we have only five indices..
        e1 = 0 if i1 == -1 else self.machines[1][i1]
        e2 = 0 if i2 == -1 else self.machines[3][i2]
        e3 = 0 if i3 == -1 else self.machines[5][i3]
        e4 = 0 if i4 == -1 else self.machines[7][i4]
        e5 = 0 if i5 == -1 else self.machines[9][i5]

        o1 = 0 if i1 == -1 else self.machines[0][i1]
        o2 = 0 if i2 == -1 else self.machines[2][i2]
        o3 = 0 if i3 == -1 else self.machines[4][i3]
        o4 = 0 if i4 == -1 else self.machines[6][i4]
        o5 = 0 if i5 == -1 else self.machines[8][i5]

        #at least the structure of our storage is nicely visible.
        return e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, o1, o2, o3, o4, o5

#since the python ints have unlimited size and are in fact objects
#they take unreasonable amount of memory if we only want to store one number
#enters bitpacking. Maybe a bit of an overkill, but I like it.
def packValues(i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, eff, out):
    return i1 | (i2 << 8) | (i3 << 16) | (i4 << 24) | (i5 << 32) | (eff << 64) | (out << 96)

#the size of our packed result is 40 bits. It could be probably shaved down further, however that would require
#multiplication instead of guessing.
#also since we now pack everything, we save additional space by not using tuples.
#our result is just a list of packed ints.
def unpackValues(packedIndices):
    idx1 = packedIndices & 0xFF
    idx2 = (packedIndices & (0xFF << 8)) >> 8
    idx3 = (packedIndices & (0xFF << 16)) >> 16
    idx4 = (packedIndices & (0xFF << 24)) >> 24
    idx5 = (packedIndices & (0xFF << 32)) >> 32
    eff = (packedIndices & (0xFFFFFFFF << 64)) >> 64
    out = (packedIndices & (0xFFFFFFFF << 96)) >> 96
    return idx1, idx2, idx3, idx4, idx5, eff, out




results = []
count = 0
mach = MachineHolder(machines)
m0len = mach.getLen(0)
m1len = mach.getLen(1)
m2len = mach.getLen(2)
m3len = mach.getLen(3)
m4len = mach.getLen(4)
for i in range(0, m0len):
    for j in range(0, m1len):
        for k in range(0, m2len):
            for l in range(0, m3len):
                for m in range(0, m4len):
                    e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, o1, o2, o3, o4, o5 = mach.getMachineInfoBatch(i, j, k, l, m)
                    totalOutput = o1 + o2 + o3 + o4 + o5
                    powerRequired = 1/e1 * o1 + 1/e2 * o2 + 1/e3 * o3 + 1/e4 * o4 + 1/e5 * o5
                    #since the values are in thousands, I think we can safely round
                    results.append(packValues(i, j, k, l, m, int(totalOutput), int(powerRequired)))
                    count += 1
                    if count % 1000000 == 0:
                        print(count, unpackValues(results[count-1]))

                    

#here we can start wasting some space since the number won't be that big anyways
#however we will need to check the array boundaries, otherwise we will crash
#also it is just a mechanical repetition of the step above, so I will leave that up to you
for i in range(0,50):
    for j in range(0,50):
        for k in range(0, 50):
            for l in range(0, 50):
                count += 1
                count += 1
                count += 1
                count += 1
                if count % 10000 == 0:
                    print(count)

for i in range(0, 50):
    for j in range(0, 50):
        for k in range(0, 50):
            count += len([x for x in itertools.combinations([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3)])
            if count % 10000 == 0:
                print(count)

for i in range(0, 50):
    for j in range(0, 50):
        count += len([x for x in itertools.combinations([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2)])
        if count % 10000 == 0:
            print(count)

for i in range(0, 50):
    count += len([x for x in itertools.combinations([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 1)])
    if count % 10000 == 0:
        print(count)

print(count)
```

Comment: Shamis, thanks for your help. You are right, the first machine (BM3) is NOT more efficient. However it is more convinient for slow output, up to ~4000. I would like to test your approach but your code is not Python.

Comment: rats, sry, I got caught up in R since I was doing something in it and I missed the tag. Your question is not language dependant though and if you find that this approach works, you can re-write the code in a much nicer & pollished way in the language of your choice.

Comment: Try running it [here](https://rstudio.cloud/projects) so that you don't need to install R because of my oversight :-) I'm sorry, but I'm currently at work so I don't have the time to rewrite it in python ^^.

Comment: To get the result, first source the code as is, then run `listEfficiencies(combinations, 15000)` in the console. If you wish to filter only the minimum values, add `TRUE` as a third parameter. 15000 can be replaced with a number of your choice ofc :-).

Comment: thanks, but I have never used  R and it would be difficult to re-write in Python if I cannot read it.

Comment: R and python are not that different. Give it a go, it will be a nice excercise. calling ?function_name in the console gives a manual, you can step through the code to look what is happening etc.

Comment: I have amended the question description thanks to your imput. tbh I am hoping for an advise in python as the tag and the stack's title says.

Comment: I am able to run it in R studio cloud. It's fast too, thanks. it would be difficult for me to re-write in python as I don't know what R does really. Plus I need to pass this tool to each row of a pandas dataframe where I store the 3 (or more) efficiency curves in a column.

Comment: Shamis, I like your combinatorial approach. Now I have to re-write it in python because I have to pass it to all the cells of pandas column data frame. In addition, I have to improve the performance too, finding some python combinatorial library if possible. As I tried the R code with 5 blowers, (the real production ones) with 50 points per efficiency line and the code blew up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225216/discussion-between-shamis-and-ganesa75).

Comment: Hi Shamis, thanks so much for this. it's a very advanced code. I am looking forward to propely understand it and test it. First thing first, please could you share how that machines.csv file looks like? I am not able to save it on R but I have the 5 original data frames in python. Each of them with shape (47,2) and df.columns = Index(['Eff', 'Flow'], dtype='object'). I see you loaded the csv and store in a list 'machines'. I simply want to know how I can to replicate that list from my 5 separate data frames So if you share the shape of your 'reader' should be a good start.

Comment: `fullTable <- cbind(machine1, machine2, machine3, machine4, machine5)`  `write.csv(fullTable, 'machines.csv')` is all the code you need on the R side to save the values. the machine1 etc. are the R data frames with data about the machines.

Comment: I am able to run it, thanks! however if I understood well, print(count) gives a bunch of iterations that show the ordinal position of the data points for each curve machine, a totalOutput and a powerRequired (the opposite of the R code). However, the beauty of the R code was that I can pass the total output required as argument in the function and get back the percentage of the efficiency for each curves and the real output of each curves.

Comment: Python scripts is working differently; the iterations show just random total outputs associated with the minimum power to produce each of them I guess. Is that correct? It is not possible to pass the total output required as an argument in any function. Why did you go for a different approach?

Comment: Printing slows everything down. So the python script is currently printing only once every 1M iterations. You will have to add the code to retrieve the values after the computation is finished.
Also if you have fewer data points and thus less stuff to store, you can replace the packed value storing by storing tuples or something less clunky.
As for retrieving the value for the code - filtering the results should be rather easy. This is not site "give me the complete solution for a complex problem". SO is more like "I am missing this one step to finish solving the problem. Please help. ^^.

Comment: The code is not complete - it just computes every possible combination of machines, their power requirements and total output. So you will have to go through the final table, look for the configurations with relevant output and compare their requirements. Then you will have your solution.

Comment: sure. is the following th best way to filter? 
reqPow_range = [item for item in (unpackValues(t) for t in results) if 15500 <= item[5] <= 16500]

Comment: `if 15500 <= int(totalOutput) <= 16500:
               results.append(packValues(i, j, k, l, m, int(totalOutput),int(powerRequired)))`
Acttually by adding the conditional statement before appending the 'results' list I save RAM. It looks like it gives the same result

Comment: I amended the question with a snippet. I would like to know a way to avoid writing a function for each combinations